# A DFS sudoku solver

Tags: beginner, rust, sudoku, depth-first-search

This is my attempt at a Sudoku solver using a DFS approach.

I mainly developed it to become a better Rust developer, but if you have any performance tips, I will be glad to hear them :)

My program works for any `dim > 1`, but these take a long time to calculate. You may wish to limit running the code to 2 or 3 dimensions.

Here are some inputs you can use to test it. If my program returns the original sudoku, then there are no solutions.

> ```
> 9 x x x 7 x 6 8 1 x x x x x 6 x 4 x x 3 x x x x x x 9 x 6 x x x 1 5 x 7 x x x x x x x x x 8 x 3 7 x x x 1 x 1 x x x x x x 3 x x 9 x 6 x x x x x 3 5 2 x 1 x x x 4
> ```

> ```
> x x x 9 x x 4 x x x x x x x 4 5 7 x 7 x x 3 x x x 1 2 1 x x x x x 2 4 x x 9 8 x x x 1 3 x x 3 4 x x x x x 5 5 2 x x x 6 x x 8 x 6 7 8 x x x x x x x 3 x x 1 x x x
> ```

> ```
> x x 1 x 6 8 5 2 x x x x 2 x x x x 1 x x 2 5 1 9 x 3 x x x 8 x 2 4 7 x x 6 x 4 x x x 3 x 2 x x 7 3 8 x 9 x x x 9 x 1 3 5 2 x x 4 x x x x 6 x x x x 8 5 4 7 x 6 x x
> ```

Here's my code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate text_io;

use std::io;



// struct to represent a sudoku
struct Sudoku {
    size: u32,
    board: Vec<Vec<u32>>,
}



fn generate_sudoku(size: u32) -> Sudoku {
    let dim = (size * size) as usize;
    let mut sudoku = Sudoku {
        size: size,
        board: Vec::new(),
    };

    // fill the sudoku with the specified values
    for row in 0..dim {
        sudoku.board.push(Vec::new());
        for _ in 0..dim {
            let num: String = read!();
            let mut is_number = true;

            for ch in num.chars() {
                if !ch.is_digit(10) {
                    is_number = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            let number = if is_number {
                let num = num.parse::<u32>().expect("Not a number! Aborting...");
                if num > (dim as u32) { 0 } else { num }
            } else {
                0
            };

            sudoku.board[row].push(number);
        }
    }

    sudoku
}


// helper function to determine whether a number is valid
fn is_valid(sudoku: &Sudoku, num: u32, row: usize, column: usize) -> bool {
    let dim = (sudoku.size * sudoku.size) as usize;
    let mut check_column = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..dim {
        check_column.push(sudoku.board[i][column]);
    }

    // check the row
    for value in &sudoku.board[row] {
        if *value == num {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check the column
    for value in &check_column {
        if *value == num {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check the box
    let box_row = (sudoku.size * ((row as u32) / sudoku.size)) as usize;
    let box_column = (sudoku.size * ((column as u32) / sudoku.size)) as usize;

    for i in box_row..box_row + (sudoku.size as usize) {
        for j in box_column..box_column + (sudoku.size as usize) {
            if sudoku.board[i][j] == num {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    true
}



fn solve_sudoku(mut sudoku: &mut Sudoku, mut row: usize, mut column: usize) -> bool {
    let dim = (sudoku.size * sudoku.size) as usize;

    if column == dim {
        row += 1;
        column = 0;
    }

    // solved!
    if row == dim {
        return true;
    }

    // skip tip values
    if sudoku.board[row][column] > 0 {
        return solve_sudoku(&mut sudoku, row, column + 1);
    }

    // guess number in cell
    for try_num in 1..(dim + 1) {
        if is_valid(&sudoku, try_num as u32, row, column) {
            sudoku.board[row][column] = try_num as u32;
            if solve_sudoku(&mut sudoku, row, column + 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    sudoku.board[row][column] = 0;
    return false;
}



fn main() {
    println!("Enter the size of your sudoku (typically 3).");
    let mut size = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut size)
        .expect("Failed to read line!");

    let size: u32 = match size.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) if num > 1 => num,
        Ok(_) => {
            panic!("Number too small! The number must be greater than 1! Aborting...");
        }
        Err(_) => {
            panic!("Not a number! Aborting...");
        }
    };

    let mut sudoku = generate_sudoku(size);
    solve_sudoku(&mut sudoku, 0, 0);
    println!("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    for row in sudoku.board {
        for column in row {
            print!("{} ", column);
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Embrace even more static analysis tools, such as [clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy). It provides warnings like:

   ```
   warning: unneeded return statement
      --> src/main.rs:120:5
       |
   120 |     return false;
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
   ```

   ```
   warning: this expression borrows a reference that is immediately dereferenced by the compiler
      --> src/main.rs:111:21
       |
   111 |         if is_valid(&sudoku, try_num as u32, row, column) {
       |                     ^^^^^^^
       |
   ```
2. Some of your documentation isn't useful: "struct to represent a sudoku" before `struct Sudoku` doesn't add anything.
3. All of the functions should be methods on `Sudoku`. Taking a struct as the first argument is a big hint.
4. Why check all the characters of input to see if it's a number, but then parse it and fail anyway? Just check the result of parsing and fallback to 0 on failure.
5. Any time you have a loop creating things for a `Vec`, try to use `collect`. It's more efficient, has less code, is more expressive and reduces the need for mutability.
6. Might as well make tiny helper to calculate the dimension.
7. Use iterators, specifically `Iterator::any` instead of the `for` loop.
8. Why create `check_column` but then potentially return early without ever using it? Create it right before it's used?
9. Actually, there's no need to create `check_column` at all, just us emore iterators.
10. Could use Itertools' cartesian product iterator adapter instead of nesting two for loops.
11. Use consistent ways of reading input.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate text_io;

struct Sudoku {
    size: u32,
    board: Vec<Vec<u32>>,
}

fn dim(size: u32) -> usize {
    (size * size) as _
}

impl Sudoku {
    fn new(size: u32) -> Sudoku {
        let dim = dim(size);

        let board = (0..dim).map(|_| {
            (0..dim).map(|_| {
                let num: String = read!();
                num.parse::<u32>().unwrap_or(0)
            }).collect()
        }).collect();

        Sudoku {
            size: size,
            board: board,
        }
    }

    // helper function to determine whether a number is valid
    fn is_valid(&self, num: u32, row: usize, column: usize) -> bool {
        // check the row
        if self.board[row].iter().any(|&value| value == num) {
            return false;
        }

        // check the column
        if self.board.iter().any(|row| row[column] == num) {
            return false;
        }

        // check the box
        let box_row = (self.size * ((row as u32) / self.size)) as usize;
        let box_column = (self.size * ((column as u32) / self.size)) as usize;

        for i in box_row..box_row + (self.size as usize) {
            for j in box_column..box_column + (self.size as usize) {
                if self.board[i][j] == num {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        true
    }

    fn solve(&mut self, mut row: usize, mut column: usize) -> bool {
        let dim = dim(self.size);

        if column == dim {
            row += 1;
            column = 0;
        }

        // solved!
        if row == dim {
            return true;
        }

        // skip tip values
        if self.board[row][column] > 0 {
            return self.solve(row, column + 1);
        }

        // guess number in cell
        for try_num in 1..(dim + 1) {
            if self.is_valid(try_num as u32, row, column) {
                self.board[row][column] = try_num as u32;
                if self.solve(row, column + 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        self.board[row][column] = 0;
        false
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("Enter the size of your sudoku (typically 3).");
    let size: String = read!();

    let size: u32 = match size.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) if num > 1 => num,
        Ok(_) => {
            panic!("Number too small! The number must be greater than 1! Aborting...");
        }
        Err(_) => {
            panic!("Not a number! Aborting...");
        }
    };

    let mut sudoku = Sudoku::new(size);
    sudoku.solve(0, 0);
    println!("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    for row in sudoku.board {
        for column in row {
            print!("{} ", column);
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```